# Javascript code not showing correct output

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am working on javascript to create weight conversion . but unfortunately i am not getting correct outut rather then i am getting **NaN** in my required text fields

```js
<script>
function Convert(valNum) {
  document.getElementById("outputPounds").innerHTML=valNum*2.2046;
  document.getElementById("outputGrams").innerHTML=valNum*1000;
  document.getElementById("outputMilligrams").innerHTML=valNum*1000000;
  document.getElementById("outputUsTons").innerHTML=valNum*0.0011023;
  document.getElementById("outputOunces").innerHTML=valNum*35.274;
}
</script>
```

```html
<form name="Weightconverter">
  <fieldset class="container">
  <label for="enterWeight" >Enter Weight in Kilogram: </label>
  <input type="text" id="kgid" name="enterWeight"/>
  <input  type="button" id="enterWeight" style="background-color:#069; width:100px; padding:5px; text-align:center" value="Convert"  onClick="Convert(this.value)"/>
  </fieldset>
        </p>
        <div class="container">
  <p>Pounds: <span id="outputPounds"></span></p>
  <p>Grams: <span id="outputGrams"></span></p>
  <p>Milligrams: <span id="outputMilligrams"></span></p>
  <p>UsTons: <span id="outputUsTons"></span></p>
  <p>Ounces: <span id="outputOunces"></span></p>
        </div>
```

Comment: this.value at the call point would be the *button* value which is not a number hence the NaN when you treat it as one.

Comment: this.value would be the BUTTON value. A simple `console.log(valNum)` would have showed you it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
 
  function Convert() {
   var valNum = document.getElementById("kgid").value;
 
    document.getElementById("outputPounds").innerHTML=valNum*2.2046;
    document.getElementById("outputGrams").innerHTML=valNum*1000;
    document.getElementById("outputMilligrams").innerHTML=valNum*1000000;
    document.getElementById("outputUsTons").innerHTML=valNum*0.0011023;
    document.getElementById("outputOunces").innerHTML=valNum*35.274;
  }
```

```html
<form name="Weightconverter" onsubmit="return false">
  <fieldset class="container">
  <label for="enterWeight" >Enter Weight in Kilogram: </label>
  <input type="text" id="kgid" name="enterWeight"/>
    <button id="enterWeight" style="background-color:#069; width:100px; padding:5px; text-align:center" onClick="Convert()">
        Convert
    </button> 
    
  </fieldset>
        </p>
        <div class="container">
  <p>Pounds: <span id="outputPounds"></span></p>
  <p>Grams: <span id="outputGrams"></span></p>
  <p>Milligrams: <span id="outputMilligrams"></span></p>
  <p>UsTons: <span id="outputUsTons"></span></p>
  <p>Ounces: <span id="outputOunces"></span></p>
        </div>
```

You need to get the value of the input field, with `document.getElementById("kgid").value` and you need to add `onsubmit="return false"` to your form as well because your form doesn't suppose to send its data to anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use parseInt inside your function.

Browsers sometime interpret the number as string, input from text field, resulting in NaN

```
 <script>
function Convert(v) {
  var valNum = parseInt(v);
    //or var valNum = Number(v);
document.getElementById("outputPounds").innerHTML=valNum*2.2046;
  document.getElementById("outputGrams").innerHTML=valNum*1000;
  document.getElementById("outputMilligrams").innerHTML=valNum*1000000;
  document.getElementById("outputUsTons").innerHTML=valNum*0.0011023;
  document.getElementById("outputOunces").innerHTML=valNum*35.274;
}
</script>
```